# How can I add extra word in permalink when someone click download button?

Tags: php, posts, custom-field, loop

I am new in here. I actually do not understand really it a WordPress related question or not. I think it is. My site runs into WordPress. My question is when someone clicks my post it shows a download button with some text. If someone clicks 'download' button it loaded and open a new page with another two download buttons. When they again click one of them it open again new page. The permalink still the same every time. But How I can it changeable like this? I used custom field for this.

1. The first click on a post it will be like this, http://www.appsapk.mobi/whatsapp-messenger/
2. After reading the post and review if they click the download button it needs to be like this, http://www.appsapk.mobi/whatsapp-messenger/platform/
3. Again click one of the button it will be like this, http://www.appsapk.mobi/whatsapp-messenger/platform/android

   ```
                               <script type="text/Javascript">
                                   function update_url(url) {
                                       history.pushState(null, '', url);
                                   }

                                   function download_btn_press() {
                                       document.getElementById("download-1").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("download-2").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-1").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-2").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-3").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-4").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-5").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("recent-review").style.display = "none";
                                   }

                                   function download_android_press() {
                                       document.getElementById("download-1").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("download-2").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("download-3").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-1").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-2").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-3").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-4").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-5").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("recent-review").style.display = "none";

                                   }

                                   function back_two() {
                                       document.getElementById("download-3").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("download-2").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-1").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-2").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-3").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-4").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("block-5").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("download-1").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("recent-review").style.display = "none";
                                   }

                                   function back_one() {
                                       document.getElementById("download-3").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("download-2").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("download-1").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-1").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-2").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-3").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-4").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("block-5").style.display = "block";
                                   }

                                   function reviews_show() {
                                       document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
                                       document.getElementById("reviews").style.display = "block";
                                   }

                                   function home_show() {
                                       document.getElementById("home").style.display = "block";
                                       document.getElementById("reviews").style.display = "none";
                                   }
                               </script>
                               <?php

                                   if(isset($_POST['download'])) {
                                       echo '<script type="text/Javascript"> window.onload = function() {download_btn_press()}; </script>';
                                   }

                                   if(isset($_POST['android-download'])) {
                                       echo '<script type="text/Javascript"> window.onload = function() {download_android_press();}; </script>';
                                   }

                                   if(isset($_POST['back-one'])) {
                                       echo '<script type="text/Javascript"> window.onload = function() { back_one(); }; </script>';
                                   }

                                   if(isset($_POST['back-two'])) {
                                       echo '<script type="text/Javascript"> window.onload = function() { back_two(); }; </script>';
                                   }

                               ?>
                               <section class="inner-banner cate-view-inner">
                                     <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                   <p><a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">Home  &nbsp; // </a> <span><?php the_title(); ?></span></p>
                                        </div>

                                       <div class="col-lg-7">
                                        <div class="searc"> <input placeholder="Search your favorite tutorials..." type="search"> <input type="button"> </div>    
                                        </div>

                                         </div>
                                         </div>
                                     </section>
                                <div class="container">
                                <div class="row"> 

                                  <!--DIV Parent of Total Blocks in inner page Start-->
                                   <div class="parentDIV"> 
                                     <div class="col-lg-12">
                                     <div class="hotel-slder" id="block-1">
                                    <div class="hotel-full-view" id="block-2">
                                    <?php 
                                       if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                       the_post_thumbnail();
                                       } 
                                    ?>
                               <h2 class="book-mark"><?php the_title(); ?>
                                </h2>

                                   <?php 

                                        $stars = ic_get_reviews_average(get_the_ID());
                                        if ($stars == 0) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars > 0 && $stars < 1) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars == 1) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars > 1 && $stars < 2) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars == 2) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars > 2 && $stars < 3) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars == 3) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars > 3 && $stars < 4) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars == 4) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars > 4 && $stars < 5) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        } elseif ($stars == 5) {
                                            echo '<span>Average Rating: <i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><span class="badge">'.$stars.'</span></span>';
                                        }

                                   ?>
                                   <p>Download Latest 2018 Version App for Mobile</p>


                               <div class="share">
                                   <!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
                               <ul>
                                   <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
                                       <li class="wonder">Wonderful!</li>
                                       <li><a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a></li>
                                       <li><a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a></li>
                                       <li><a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a></li>
                                       <li><a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a></li>
                                   </div>  
                               </ul>
                               <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
                               <!-- AddToAny END -->
                               </div>

                               </div>

                                    </div>

                               <div class="hotel-add" id="block-3">
                               <!-- Single Page Adsense Ad Code -->

                               </div>

                                  <!-- /clearfix -->  

                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                     <div class='full-des' style='margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 25px' id='recent-review'>
                                       <?php
                                           $args = array(
                                           'number' => '1',
                                               'post_id' => $post->ID
                                           );
                                           $comments = get_comments($args);
                                           if($comments) {
                                               echo '<h2>Recent Review</h4><hr>';
                                           foreach($comments as $comment) :
                                                   echo '<h4>'.get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID,'ic_review_title',true).'</h4>';
                                                   display_stars(get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID,'ic_review_rating',true));
                                                   echo '<br>Posted By: <b>'.$comment->comment_author.'<br />'.$comment->meta_key.'</h4></b>';
                                                   echo '<br>" '.$comment->comment_content.' "<hr>';
                                               endforeach;
                                           } else {
                                               echo '<h2>Recent Review</h2><hr>';
                                               echo '<br /><p>No Recent Reviews found!</p>';
                                           }
                                       ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="full-des">
                                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                 <ul class="nav nav-tabs hotel-tabs" role="tablist" id="block-4">
                                   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" onclick="home_show()" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i> Summary</a></li>

                                   <li role="presentation"><a href="#reviews" onclick="reviews_show()" aria-controls="reviews" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i> Reviews</a></li>
                                 </ul>

                                 <!-- Tab panes -->
                                   <div class="tab-content">
                                   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home"> 
                                   <div class="summery">
                                   <div id="block-5">
                                       <?php echo the_content();?> 
                                       <br /><br />
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="download-section">
                                           <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                   <div class="row">
                                                       <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                           <div class="app-image">
                                                               <?php 
                                                                   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                                                       the_post_thumbnail();
                                                                   } 
                                                               ?>
                                                           </div>
                                                       </div>
                                                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                           <h2 class="book-mark"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                                       </div>

                                                   </div>

                                                   <div class="row" id="download-1">
                                                       <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                       <form method="POST" action="">
                                                           <input type="hidden" name="download"/>
                                                           <button type="submit" class="app-download"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> Download</button>
                                                       </form>
                                                       </div>
                                                       <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                                               <i class="fab fa-android fa-2x"></i>
                                                           </button>
                                                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                                               <i class="fab fa-apple fa-2x"></i>
                                                           </button>
                                                       </div>
                                                   </div>

                                                   <div class="row" id="download-2" style="display: none;">
                   <div class='row' id='sub-block-1'>
                       <div class="col-lg-12">
                           <p class="text-center">
                               <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Pick your platform to download
                           </p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class='row'>
                       <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <img src="" alt="Your Ad Goes Here!" style="width: 100%;"/>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-8" style="text-align: center;">

                           <form action="" method="POST">
                               <input type="hidden" name="android-download"/>
                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default app-download" style="width: 90%; margin: 5%;">
                                   <i class="fab fa-android"></i> Download for Android
                               </button>
                           </form>

                           <br />
                           <?php
                               echo "<a href='".get_field('ios_download_link')."' alt='' target='_blank'>";
                           ?>
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default app-download" style="width: 90%; margin: 5%;">
                                   <i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download for iOS
                               </button>
                           </a>

                           <form action="" method="POST">
                               <input type="hidden" name="back-one"/>
                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-back" name="back-one">
                                   <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x back"></i>
                               </button>
                           </form>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="row" id="download-3" style="display: none;">
                   <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;">
                       <p>
                           <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Download Now
                       </p>
                       <?php
                           echo "<a href='".get_field('android_download_link')."' alt='' target='_blank'>";
                       ?>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default app-download" style="width: 90%; margin: 5%;">
                               <i class="fab fa-android"></i> Click to Download
                           </button>
                       </a>

                       <form action="" method="POST">
                           <input type="hidden" name="back-two"/>
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-back" name="back-two">
                               <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x back"></i>
                           </button>
                       </form>

                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-lg-12">
                       <h5>
                           <b>Price:</b> Free
                       </h5>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-lg-6">
                       <div class="rating">
                           <h3>
                               Average User Rating
                           </h3>
                           <?php
                               $stars = ic_get_reviews_average(get_the_ID());

                               if ($stars == 0) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars > 0 && $stars < 1) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars == 1) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars > 1 && $stars < 2) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars == 2) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars > 2 && $stars < 3) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars == 3) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars > 3 && $stars < 4) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars == 4) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="far fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars > 4 && $stars < 5) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star-half yellow"></i></span>';
                               } elseif ($stars == 5) {
                                   echo '<span><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i><i class="fas fa-star yellow"></i></span>';
                                                                   }
                                                               ?>
                                                               <?php
                                                                   $totals = ic_get_product_review_totals(get_the_ID());

                                                                   echo '<p>'.$totals['total'].' Votes</p>';
                                                               ?>
                                                           </div>
                                                       </div>
                                                       <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                           <div class="list">
                                                               Uninstall the app
                                                               <ol>
                                                                   <li>Go to Settings menu.</li>
                                                                   <li>Choose Apps or Application Manager.</li>
                                                                   <li>Touch the app you want to remove.</li>
                                                                   <li>Press Uninstall.</li>
                                                               </ol>
                                                           </div>
                                                       </div>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                               </div>


                               <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane reviews-view" id="reviews" style="display: none; transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;"> 
                                 <div class="rati">

                                 </div>


                               <div class="right-side-doctors-list room-list">

                               </div>

                               <div class="sr">
                                  <?php ic_reviews(); ?>
                                   <!-- <div class="btn system-bnt pull-right"><a href="#">Submit Your Review</a></div> -->

                                </div>
                                   </div>

                                </div>
                                   </div>

                                    <!--Right Side Doctors List End--> 

                                 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                                     </div>
   ```